# I have to link file system with elastic search. Using command line curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed fsriver and mapper plugins to  elasticserach but what is next step? how to map local file path. Not getting exact steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. install river :

   > bin/plugin -install fr.pilato.elasticsearch.river/fsriver/1.3.1

version 1.3.1 is compatible with ES 1.3

2. create your river :

   > ```
   > PUT _river/mydocs/_meta
   > {
   >   "type": "fs",
   >   "fs": {
   >     "url": "/tmp",
   >     "includes": "*.doc,*.pdf",
   >     "excludes": "resume",
   >     "update_rate": "15m"
   >   }
   > }
   > ```

this will index your document as follow :

- index : mydocs
- type : doc
- local directory : /tmp (use C:\tmp for Windows )
- indexed documents : *.pdf, *.doc
- excluded documents : resume*
- index every : 15 minutes

see advanced settings [here](https://github.com/dadoonet/fsriver/tree/v1.3.1/#version-131-for-elasticsearch-13)